# Highlight code between brackets

Tags: plugins, ide, syntax-highlighting, bluej

I have been programming for a long time in BlueJ and get used to some of stupid, yet useful things it has, like boxing the code between brackets, like in the code seen here: [image]

Do you know of any IDE or plugin for it that can do this? BlueJ is too simple for my needs and it only allows to program in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started programming this year too, also with BlueJ. After a few months we switched to Netbeans and I had exactly the same question as you.

When I look at your screenshot now, I don't like it at all anymore... I suggest you just start using Netbeans, make some programs and once you're used to it, you won't need those colours. In fact, I wouldn't want them anymore now.

I know I'm not answering your question, but just leave BlueJ. ;)

Comment: Yes, I know haha. I actually used to use other IDEs before bluej, but the school decided that for java they would use bluej, and I reallu regret, to be honest, because this stupid thing of coloring is useful. But yeah, I'm really getting used to vim, which I highly recommend (and which netbeans has a plugin for, btw) and productivity went UP a lot. Thank you anyway and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Between Brackets do you mean { } boxes? 
Because personally I use komodo as a basic text editor as it has auto complete functions along with block programming the { ].

Comment: Not exactly. If you take a look to the image, you will see that, for instance, the first IF statement has a slightly grey background. Likewise, the whole method has a yellow background, from 'private boolean...' to the end of the method (to the final closing bracket). I don't know if I'm explaining it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Shift + Alt + arrow_up   but many people dont realize you can just double click the delimiter (like a bracket) and it will highlight the entire scope.  Try double clicking your if statements bracket for example and watch eclipse highlight the entire scope.